# Resume or set start time on Brightcove video

Tags: javascript, html5-video, brightcove

I am using Brightcove player http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/ with Angular to do a popup video. I want to be able to resume it after the popup is closed.

I found this module that I can pause, resume or set start time:

http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/references/symbols/brightcove.api.modules.VideoPlayerModule.html

However, their doc is somewhat out of date. For example, this doesn't work

```
var APIModules = brightcove.modules.APIModules;
var videoPlayer = experience.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
```

Even though I have included the js files:

```
<script src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
<script src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/APIModules_all.js"></script>
```

It said `ReferenceError: experience is not defined` in the console.

Can you point me a direction on how to successfully use the `pause()` or `seek()` function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `APIModules_all.js` script. That loads an older version of the API that only works with Flash players.

Add params to the player embed code to load the smart player API:

```
<param name="includeAPI" value="true">
<param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onLoad">
<param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onReady">
```

`onLoad` could look like this

```
var videoPlayer;
function onTemplateLoad(id) {
  var experience = brightcove.api.getExperience(id);
  videoPlayer = experience.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER)
}
```

The template load event is too early to interact with playback, as no video is loaded yet. Wait for the ready event before using `videoPlayer.play()`.